# Not enough space to upgrade Redhat kernel

Tags: rhel, kernel

I am trying to upgrade a server to : kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-696.23.1.el6.

I got the message :

```
Transaction Check Error:
  installing package kernel-2.6.32-696.23.1.el6.x86_64 needs 29MB on the /boot filesystem

Error Summary
-------------
Disk Requirements:
  At least 29MB more space needed on the /boot filesystem.
```

We currently have two kernels installed:

**rpm -q kernel**

```
kernel-2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.x86_64
kernel-2.6.32-696.20.1.el6.x86_64
```

We find remaining packages from old versions in the /boot folder:

**ls -lah /boot/*2.6.32-504*| nl**

```
 1  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 104K Mar 10  2015 /boot/config-2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64
 2  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 104K May 29  2015 /boot/config-2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64
 3  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 104K Dec 19  2014 /boot/config-2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64
 4  -rw------- 1 root root  18M May  6  2015 /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64.img
 5  -rw------- 1 root root  18M May 12  2016 /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64.img
 6  -rw------- 1 root root  18M May 12  2016 /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64.img.bak
 7  -rw------- 1 root root  18M Feb  4  2015 /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64.img
 8  -rw------- 1 root root 4.5M Sep 23  2016 /boot/initrd-2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64kdump.img
 9  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 196K Mar 10  2015 /boot/symvers-2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64.gz
10  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 196K May 29  2015 /boot/symvers-2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64.gz
11  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 196K Dec 19  2014 /boot/symvers-2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64.gz
12  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.5M Mar 10  2015 /boot/System.map-2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64
13  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.5M May 29  2015 /boot/System.map-2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64
14  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.5M Dec 19  2014 /boot/System.map-2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64
15  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0M Mar 10  2015 /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64
16  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0M May 29  2015 /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64
17  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0M Dec 19  2014 /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64
```

All attempts to delete the files are unsuccessful:

**rm /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64.img.bak**

```
rm: remove regular file `/boot/initramfs-2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64.img.bak'? y
rm: cannot remove `/boot/initramfs-2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64.img.bak': Read-only file system
```

Any ideas to solve the problem?

Regards

Answer (score 4):

Install `yum-utils` package then remove the old kernels :

```
# package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=2
```

`count=2` will keep only 2 kernels.
To keep the runing kernel:

```
# package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=1
```

Comment: Thank's! I didn't ask, but your suggestion is very good and helpful for me. Earlier, I removed all old kernels by hand.

Comment: Seems the OP may need to remount /boot as read-write before this will be successful?

Comment: Thanks, I managed to remove an old kernel kernel-devel-2.6.32-696.3.1.el6.x86_64, but the free space on the /boot did not change at all!

Comment: @Jeff Schaller, How do I remount /boot as read-write ?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for you help, the /boot was mounted in RO mode, I changed that by :

```
mount -o remount,rw /boot
```

Then I deleted the files remaining from old versions in the /boot folder:

```
rm -fr $(ls | grep "2.6.32-504")
```

And I got enough space to upgrade the kernel.

Remaining question, is it advised to put back the /boot in RO mode ?

Regards